# Adding a scroll bar to Tab Panel

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

How to add a `Scroll Bar` (Both Vertical and horizontal) to a `Pabpanel`. When the `Browser` width/height is small than the `tabpanel` i need to display it.

Comment: You mean your browser does not show scrollbars (for the whole page, not the tab bar), which layout you use? Can you correct any issues with your question - I'm not sure I understand the bit after the last `tabpanel`.

Answer (score 1):

To add scrollbars to a tabpanel you need to give the tabpanel a minWidth and minHeight, then place the tabpanel in a container with autoScroll set to true. Depending on what version of Ext JS you're using there may be other layout settings that need to be set (such as shrinkWrap in 4.1.1).

For the sake of aesthetics, you may be better off scrolling the panels inside the tabpanel rather than the tabpanel itself, but that's up to you.